# How to attach description to images on ASP server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, devexpress

I'd like to create a website where image files appear in a gallery. The images should include a short description, appearing in a textbox under them. Also, a specific user should be able to *upload* images and add a description. Is there some ASP or DevExpress control that makes this easy? (So far I'm storing the descriptions in an xml file and I can read from them alright, but at upload this solution seems a bit difficult. The authentication is already implemented, it's not part of the problem)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Image and Data Browsing Controls for ASP.NET](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxImageAndDataNavigationDemos/Default.aspx) provided by DevExpress.. There you can modify the view as you want.

You should also go through section:
[Image and Data Navigation - Image Gallery](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxImageAndDataNavigationDemos/ImageGallery/DataBinding.aspx)

> In this demo, the image gallery control is bound to a standard
>   XmlDataSource type data source by specifying the DataSourceID
>   property. The FullscreenViewerThumbnailUrlField, ImageUrlField,
>   TextField, and ThumbnailUrlField properties are used to get the
>   corresponding property values from specified fields.

Comment: OK, my very specific problem is that I use an xmldatasource for the image titles and can't implement a 2-way data binding to change them.